# Apollo - Updating cache when some fields in some results are missing

Tags: graphql, apollo, missing-data, apollo-client, typepolicies

For the following query, in *some* objects in the `results` array, some of the requested fields might not be present in the response (for example `photo` or `address`), which causes the `data` of my `useQuery` to be `undefined` (without any error or warning).

```js
people(xyz: { q: $q, offset: $offset, rows: $rows }) {
  results {
    uri          <--- this is a field of type ID!
    name
    photo
    address {
      city
      country
    }
  }
}
```

My fix is to specifically check if the field exists in the incoming data and provide a fallback value, i.e.: pass a type policy for `Person` to be `{keyFields: false}` and do this in the `merge` function:

```
newItem = {...item};
newItem.photo = item.photo ?? null;
newItem.address = item.address ?? {city: "", country: ""};
```

Is the reason for having to do this that there's no `id` field in the `Person` type (instead, `uri` is of type `ID!`)?

Can I handle this in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a better way [on Apollo GraphQL's GitHub](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6736).

I'd still appreciate a solution where I don't have to go over each type's nullable field in turn, if there is one.

```js
function nullable() {
  // Create a generic field policy that allows any field to be null by default:
  return {
    read(existing = null) {
      return existing;
    },
  };
}

new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Person: {
      fields: {
        photo: nullable(),
        address: nullable(),
      },
    },
    Address: { // If there's the case of either city or country missing
      fields: {
        city: nullable(), 
        country: nullable(),
      }
    }
  },
})
```